# Greatest Integer, Least Integer functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Two positive real numbers, $a$ and $b$, are expressed as the sum of $m$ positive real numbers and $n$ positive real numbers respectively as follows:

$a = s_1 + s_2 + s_3 + s_4 + \cdots + s_m$

$b = t_1 + t_2 + t_3 + t_4 + \cdots + t_n$

For any real number $x$, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$ and $\lceil x\rceil$ denotes the least integer greater than or equal to $x$.

If $\lfloor a\rfloor = \lceil s_1\rceil + \lceil s_2\rceil + \lceil s_3\rceil + \cdots + \lceil s_m\rceil - 11$ and $\lceil b\rceil = \lfloor t_1\rfloor + \lfloor t_2\rfloor + \lfloor t_3\rfloor + \cdots + \lfloor t_n\rfloor +7$

What is the minimum possible value of $m+n$ ?

**My attempt so far :-**

I have no clue on what properties to apply , so I started by checking with some values

Since $a>0$ and also $\lfloor a\rfloor \ge 0$

I took a case for minimum value of when $\lfloor a\rfloor = 0$ which would imply $0\le a<1$,  now intuitively by taking $s_1, s_2, s_3,\ldots,s_{12}$ to be very small values between $0$ and $1$, I should be able to create the sum to lie between $0$ and $1$, and also each of $12 \lceil s\rceil$ would give value as $1$ which would satisfy our condition, so $m=12$ would be the smallest value

I have no clue on how to fit values for the second set of equations involving $b$ and $t$.

All I can say is $\lceil b\rceil \ge 7$

Also, I am extremely skeptical about my initial approach for finding $\min(m)$ as well.

Please guide me on how to solve this.

Comment: Your idea why m=12 works is good. Now you need an argument why you can't do it with $m<12$. If that's hard to, try to solve a smaller problem, like when instead of $...-11$ it says $...-1$ or $...-2$.

Comment: My first comment was "off by one". $m=11$ works as well (and is the minumum).

Comment: Please, don't use unusual characters that won't render properly in every device. Use `\lfloor` for $\lfloor$, `rfloor` for $\rfloor$, `\lceil` for $\lceil$, `rceil` for $\rceil$. Also, use `\le` for $\le$ and `\ge` for $\ge$. Take a look at my edits of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea of $m=12$ was reasonable, although you still needed to prove that $m\not<12$! I'm pretty sure my answer is right, but there most likely will be something wrong.

Lets start with $a$!
Since $0\leq{a-\lfloor{a}\rfloor}<1$, the expression can be transformed into this:
$$a=\lceil{s_1}\rceil+\lceil{s_2}\rceil+\lceil{s_3}\rceil+\cdots+\lceil{s_m}\rceil-k,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 10<k\leq11$$
Then we can express $\lceil{s_i}\rceil$ as $s_i+\varepsilon_i$, where $0\leq\varepsilon_i<1$. Plugging that in we get:
$$a=s_1+\varepsilon_1+s_2+\varepsilon_2+\cdots+s_m+\varepsilon_m-k,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 10<k\leq11$$
Since $\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2+\cdots+\varepsilon_m$ must perfectly cancel out with $-k$, the minimum $m$ value will be $11$.

The procedure for $b$ will be very similar!
Since $0\leq{\lceil{b}\rceil-b}<1$, the expression can be transformed into this:
$$b=\lfloor{t_1}\rfloor+\lfloor{t_2}\rfloor+\lfloor{t_3}\rfloor+\cdots+\lfloor{t_n}\rfloor+p,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 6<p\leq7$$
Then we can express $\lfloor{t_i}\rfloor$ as $t_i-\delta_i$, where $0\leq\delta_i<1$. Plugging that in we get:
$$b=t_1-\delta_1+t_2-\delta_2+\cdots+t_n-\delta_n+p,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 6<p\leq7$$
Since $-\delta_1-\delta_2-\cdots-\delta_n$ must perfectly cancel out with $p$, the minimum $n$ value will be $7$.

Thus we can conclude that the minimum possible value of $m+n$ is $11+7=18$.

Here are two examples for $a$ and $b$!

($a$ 1.) $21.1=1.05+10\cdot2.005$
($a$ 2.) $21=2+10\cdot3-11$

($b$ 1.) $13.9=7\cdot\frac{139}{70}$
($b$ 2.) $14=7\cdot1+7$

Comment: Good solution. Given an example in each case that $m=11$ and $n=7$ are obtainable would make it even better.

Comment: Thanks for recommending me to add examples. They would really be helpful!

Comment: Thank you @Gimbrint, I have two queries :- Firstly how did you arrive at $10<k<=11$ and secondly why does $\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2+...+\varepsilon_m$ need to cancel with k ?

Comment: The Greatest Integer that is less than $x$ is the same thing as $x$ minus some number that i will call $g$ that is less than 1. I then carried that over to the RHS and simplified it with $11$ to get a value that is greater than 10, but smaller or equal to 11 (we will subtract it). At the end i realized that $\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2+...+\varepsilon_m$ must cancel with $k$, since we are given that $a=s_1+s_2+...+s_m$. I hope this explains some of the confusion.

Comment: I am not able to understand what is the initial equation that you are manipulating , how is this k comin up at the first place , can you please elaborate the introduction of k in your solution

Comment: I started with: $\lfloor{a}\rfloor=\lceil{s_1}\rceil+\lceil{s_2}\rceil+\lceil{s_3}\rceil+...+\lceil{s_m}\rceil-11$. Then i expressed $\lfloor{a}\rfloor$ as $a-g$, where $0\leq{g}<1$. Then i moved the $g$ value to the RHS (right hand side) to get this expression: $a=\lceil{s_1}\rceil+\lceil{s_2}\rceil+\lceil{s_3}\rceil+...+\lceil{s_m}\rceil-(11-g)$. Then i labeled $11-g$ as $k$. From $0\leq{g}<1$, we can conclude that $10<k\leq11$.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Gimbrint, after reaching the step $\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2+...+\varepsilon_m=k$, how could you tell that the minimum value of m will be 11.  I can infer that $10<\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2+...+\varepsilon_m<=11$

Comment: Since $0\leq\varepsilon_i<1$, we know we will need at least $11$ $\varepsilon_i$ terms to be able to cancel $k$, since $10<k\leq11$.

Comment: Because, since $0\leq\varepsilon_i<1$, $10$ $\varepsilon_i$ terms will add up to at most $<10$. But because $10<k\leq11$, that wont be sufficient for the sum of the $\varepsilon_i$ terms to completely cancel out with $k$.